# how to set kubectl context

Tags: docker, kubernetes

i am trying to create a Kubernetes cluster with the intention of hosting a docker registry, but after installing kubectl (via homebrew on Mac) along with minikube i am getting `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` when i run `kubectl version` or any other commands. I have previously used the docker desktop app with Kubernetes so don't know if there is any config i need to replace?

I have discovered there is no context set in the kubectl config but if i run `kubectl config get-contexts` there is nothing there.

Comment: FYI, you can use `minikube kubectl -- <kubectl_cmd>` to run `kubectl` commands inside your `minikube` cluster. For example, `minikube kubectl -- get pods -A`.

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/the-connection-to-the-server-localhost-8080-was-refused-did-you-specify-the-right-host-or-port/1464/9) mentions:

> That error should only come up if you have no contexts configured in your client.
> If you run `kubectl config view` and you get something like this:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl config view
> apiVersion: v1
> clusters: []
> contexts: []
> current-context: ""
> kind: Config
> preferences: {}
> users: []
> ```
>
> Then no contexts are configured.

And:

> Getting `kubectl` to run really depends on how you installed it.
> Basically, if you install and have a proper config file, it should always work.
>
> So, either an old file from a previous installation is there or something silly like that (although usually difficult to spot).
>
> Also, make sure the commands don’t fail (some on the post pasted that the step to copy the `kubectl config` failed). That is the way to authorize to the cluster, so it won’t never work if that step doesn’t work

Example of possible resolution:

```bash
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config
kubectl get nodes
```

(From "[Creating a cluster with `kubeadm`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#more-information)")